# kotlin cast to Predicate

Tags: kotlin, predicate

I have the below error when i tried to cast to Predicate

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> com.digital.test.WebClientErrorHandler$WebClientErrorHandlerBuilder$1
> cannot be cast to class java.util.function.Predicate
> (com.digital.test.WebClientErrorHandler$WebClientErrorHandlerBuilder$1
> is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.util.function.Predicate is
> in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

```
class WebClientErrorHandlerBuilder {
    private var functionalErrorPredicate: Predicate<HttpStatus>

    init {
        functionalErrorPredicate = (HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST::equals as Predicate<HttpStatus>).or(HttpStatus.CONFLICT::equals).or(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND::equals)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Kotlin function is not a `Predicate`, so you cannot cast with the `as` operator.

You can use a [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html#sam-conversions) to do this instead. The syntax looks like you are calling a constructor:

```
Predicate(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST::equals)
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Predicate.isEqual`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#isEqual-java.lang.Object-):

```
Predicate.isEqual<HttpStatus>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
```

The `or` calls also takes `Predicate`s, but there is an implicit conversion from function references to Java functional interfaces, so no problems there.

Finally, also consider writing this whole thing as a Kotlin function `(HttpStatus) -> Boolean`. Most of the time, you don't need anything special from the Java `Predicate` API when writing Kotlin.

```
class WebClientErrorHandlerBuilder {
    private var functionalErrorPredicate: (HttpStatus) -> Boolean = {
        it in setOf(
            HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
            HttpStatus.CONFLICT,
            HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
        )
    }
}
```